# Load options dictionary using generator expression

Tags: python, dictionary, generator-expression

I have option file in this format:

`key value\t\n`

**N:B:.** Some values show tab after it.

I use Code like :

```
        src               = open("conf.cfg").readlines()
        item          =  item.split(" ")[0:2]
        key           =   item[0]
        value         =   item[1]
        dict_[key]    = value
```

Can I use generator expression to get the same result ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension, for example:

```
with open("conf.cfg") as f:
    dict_ = {key: value 
             for key, value in (line.strip().split(" ")[:2] 
                                for line in f)}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a dictionary comprehension though, not a generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a generator expression, it would look like this:

```
with open("conf.cfg") as f:
    dict_ = dict(line.split() for line in f)
```

I am assuming you don't have spaces in the keys or values.  If you have spaces in them (and "they are quoted" strings) then it will be easier for you to read your file with the `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way:

```
with open('config.txt') as f:
    dict_ = {k: v for k, v in (line.split() for line in f.readlines())}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using generator function:

```
def myGenerator():
    with open("conf.cfg") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            yield(line.split())

result = {k:v for k,v in myGenerator()}

print result
```

Comment: why are you using a `defaultdict` instead of a `dict` here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out..I was experimenting with defaultdict and forgot to cleanup. Now, i have modified..it looks better now...Thanks again...